# Basic jQuery carousel from scratch

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, carousel

I would use one of the readily available jQuery plugins, but none of them fit my needs for this particular site.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pushState.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav a.slide").click(function() {
        var img = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
        $('#content').hide().css({ 'background':'url('+ img +') no-repeat 50% 50%' }).fadeIn('3000');
        var remApp = $(this).prev('a.slide');
        remApp.remove();
        $("#nav").append(remApp);
    });
});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
#content {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
z-index: 1;
}
#nav {
position: absolute;
top: 70%;
z-index: 3;
}
#nav a.slide {
margin: 0 20px 0 0;
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav .slide img {
width: 100px;
height: 85px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="content">


</div>
<div id="social_links">

</div>
<div id="nav">

<a href="#" class="slide">
<img src="images/slide1.gif" />
</a>

<a href="#" class="slide">
<img src="images/slide2.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="#" class="slide">
<img src="images/slide3.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="#" class="slide">
<img src="images/slide4.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="#" class="slide">
<img src="images/slide5.png" />
</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This takes the image that you click on and removes it, then appends it to the end. I need it to take each of the previous images and append them.

Also, it seems to have a one-time rule. I can make each of the images go once, but then nothing happens.

You can see it in "action" [here](http://sarahnwatson.com/new/)

Comment: What features do you need the aren't available in one of the existing plugins?

Comment: +1 for writing your own.

Comment: Thanks Toast :) @Clive, I need to write my own because it is such an instrumental part of the site i'm designing. It needs to have very specific rules and functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event handlers are being removed from the slides when you use `.remove`. Per the jQuery documentation (emphasis mine):

> Use `.remove()` when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, **all bound events and jQuery data** associated with the elements are removed. To remove the elements without removing data and events, use **.detach()** instead.

I wouldn't remove it or detatch it though. Just append it and jQuery will automatically put it at the end. Since you want to move all previous siblings to the end too, you want this:

```
var remApp = $(this).prev('a.slide');
$("#nav").append(remApp.prevAll().andSelf());
```

Note that I removed the `.remove` command and I added `.prevAll().andSelf()` to `remApp`. `.prevAll()` gets all previous siblings (but not `remApp`) and `.andSelf()` rejoins `remApp` to the collection. Then you append the whole collection to the end of the list.

Comment: Yay! That worked! Now what about doing it to each slide that is before the one you're clicking on?

Comment: @sun-tzu I'm not sure I understand. What do you need to do to each slide *before the one you're clicking on*?

Comment: The same thing that it's already doing, just with each one. Right now it is removing and appending only one element. I need it to take all of the elements that are before the one being clicked on. I know jQuery has an each() function, but I can't figure out how to make that work in this case.

Comment: @sun-tzu Ok gotcha. I updated my response. Don't forget to mark it as the answer if you like it :)

Comment: you're my hero @Jeff! One more thing if possible... Is there any way to add a little bit of an animation to this so that the element slides in to replace the ones that it's removing?

Comment: Unfortunately, you wont be able to do any sliding with this technique. The best you can do without rewriting it from scratch would be to `.fadeOut` before the `.append` and `.fadeIn` after.

Comment: Well I'm not opposed to rewriting... any ideas @Jeff?

Comment: :) First, I would recommend that you use a prepackaged plugin like http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/. If you still want to roll your own, you would need to `.animate` the `left` and/or `top` css properties of each item when it is selected instead of `.append`ing the items.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible issues (solving one of them should help) resulting from the fact, that the events are bound to the elements, and when the elements are removed and added again, the events are not bound to the elements any more. In other words you remove the element from the DOM along with deleting the events attached, but when you insert them in the DOM again, the events are not re-attached.

There are two ways you can fix it:

- do not attach events to the elements, but to the container, and then delegate the events (using jQuery's [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function) to the elements you need, eg. like that:

  ```
  $("#nav").delegate('a.slide', 'click', function() {
      var img = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
      $('#content').hide().css({ 'background':'url('+ img +') no-repeat 50% 50%' }).fadeIn('3000');
      var remApp = $(this).prev('a.slide');
      remApp.remove();
      $("#nav").append(remApp);
  });
  ```
- when removing the elements, do it using [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/), not [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) jQuery's function - it will remove the elements without deleting the events. As `.remove()`'s documentation says:

  > Similar to .empty(), the .remove() method takes elements out of the
  >   DOM. Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well
  >   as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all
  >   bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.
  >   **To remove the elements without removing data and events, use .detach()
  >   instead.**